# The coarse moduli space of a weighted projective line

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, coarse-moduli-spaces

Fix two positive integers $a$ and $b$. Consider a weighted projective line $\mathbb{P}(a,b)$ as a quotient stack
$$[(\mathbb{C}^2-\{0\})/\mathbb{C}^*]$$
where $\mathbb{C}^*$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^2-\{0\}$ by $$\lambda \cdot (x,y) = (\lambda^a x,\lambda^b y).$$
Then $\mathbb{P}(a,b)$ has its underlying quotient space $|\mathbb{P}(a,b)| = (\mathbb{C}^2-\{0\})/\mathbb{C}^*$ as a coarse moduli space. It's known that $\mathbb{P}(a,b)$ also has the usual projective line $\mathbb{P}^1$ as its coarse moduli space (which I believe is not true in higher dimensions).

What's the morphism $\mathbb{P}(a,b) \to \mathbb{P}^1$ corresponding to the coarse moduli space $\mathbb{P}^1$? In other words, how to show that $|\mathbb{P}(a,b)|$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: Isn't the coarse moduli space of any weighted projective space just projective space?

Comment: I think you send $(x,y) \to (x^b,y^a)$? I believe the obvious generalization to higher dimensions works too.

Comment: @HarryGindi Do you have a reference for this result?

Comment: @Asvin This is a well-defined map. But I think it's not bijective in the level of quotient spaces.

Comment: @HarryGindi: this is not true in general (but ok in dimension $1$). They are all toric varieties, and so can be described by their fans. I believe that $\mathbf P(d_0,\ldots,d_n)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf P^n$ if and only if it is smooth; but already things like $\mathbf P(1,1,2)$ are singular! See for example Dolgachev's [*Weighted projective varieties*](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0101508) ([available on his website](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~idolga/weighted82.pdf)), 1.2.3 and Prop. 1.3.3(iii), complemented with Fulton's [*Toric varieties*](https://doi.org/10.1515/9781400882526), §2.2.

Comment: This is also the whole point of using stacky blowups in the new approach to resolution of singularities in characteristic $0$ by Abramovich–Temkin–Włodarczyk and McQuillan: unlike the course spaces, the stacky weighted projective spaces are *smooth*.

Comment: I think @Asvin's suggestion is right, except you need to divide by their $\gcd$ (which is often assumed $1$). The proof is by computing the (GIT) invariants, or computing the $\operatorname{Proj}$ of the obvious graded ring. There *is* no "obvious generalisation to higher dimension".

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Do you have a reference for the proof?

Comment: It seems to be a special case of Prop. 1.3.1 in Dolgachev's paper (linked above). (Typo: I think it should be $q_0/a_0$, not $q_0/a$. The latter is not an integer.) Specifically, see the second corollary of 1.3.1.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thanks!

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Ah yeah, I think the thing I was thinking of was that the coarse moduli space is always Proj of the weighted polynomial ring.